# inner join using Linq Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, join

I'm trying to join two datatables of same keyfields.

table1

```
ID     Class    
----   -----
1       10  
2       9
```

table2

```
ID     Class
----   -----
1       8   
2       7
```

Result

```
ID      Class1    Class2
1        10       8
2        9        7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

following is code for joining between user and userclients you can replace your table and get the result of join

Follwing image is for the c# but will give you idea in detail

[image]

```
Dim user = From u In Users Join uc In UserClients On u.Id = uc.UserId New From { _
    u.Id, _
    u.FirstName, _
    u.LastName, _
    uc.MobileNo, _
    uc.imeiNO, _
    uc.Id _
}
```

if you are beginner you can look this :
[SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

Answer (score 4):

try something like this:

```
Dim test = From t1 in table1_
       Join t2 in table2 on t1.ID Equals t2.ID _
       Select  ID = t1.ID,
               Class1 = t1.Class,
               Class2 = t2.Class
```